# Manually add package to conda environment when pip fails?

Tags: pip, conda

I am trying to add a package to my conda environment.  The package is not available in conda, is available through pip, but pip fails during building it.  I can, however, manually build the C++ code.

Is there a manual process I can follow to get the compiled code into my conda environment in such a way that the conda package manager will return it when requested, as if it had successfully been built and installed by pip?

Comment: Have you included compiler(s) in the environment?

Comment: @merv, yes the environment has a working C compiler (even though it's having trouble compiling one package using the pip process).  But for this question just accept that pip won't work on one package on this machine; I'm really wondering what conda does if pip does succeed and how I can manually mimic that.

Comment: Conda doesn't do anything special with Pip-installed packages, just detects their presence. Drop the package into the environment's `site-packages` and Conda should detect it. The reason I ask about the compiler is that Conda compiler packages often export environment variables that are needed for resolving linked libraries. E.g., one gets this for free with Conda Forge's `compilers` metapackage, but directly installing `gcc` may not do the same setup.